# How to merge changes to local repository

Tags: github

I have a repository on github.com, where I made changes in the README.md file from the github editor. A copy of the repository is on my localmachine and contains local commits.

Looking for advice for merging the github changes and local changes without overwriting local commits.

Comment: Sync doesn't merge the files?

Comment: I am not using any clients (github clients), i am trying to do it from  Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You have a merge conflict which happens when two sides both modified the same file.

First, make sure to commit your local changes. Then `git pull`. When there are merge conflicts that can't be automatically resolved, you'll have to open the respective files in a text editor and manually choose which lines you want from which side. This is how this will look.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
Text added locally
=======
Text added on the remote
>>>>>>> master
```

After you corrected the line and removed the separators added by git, `git add` the file and finish the merge with `git commit`. Since you committed your local changes before, you can always rollback in case that you messed up the conflicting files.

For further information, I suggest to read the Github guide about [resolving merge conflicts](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line).

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to pull only one file, I mean only the one in which the change is done.

Comment: You can pull commits, not files. Git can merge single files but that is nothing for you to worry about here, because the web interface created a commit for your changes. Moreover, only the changes will pulled anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Before merging to your local repository, it's best to commit all your pending changes first.

The simplest way to merge the changes is with `git merge`:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

(Shortcut: `git pull origin master`)

Another option is to rebase on top the changes with `git rebase`:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
```

(Shortcut: `git pull --rebase origin master`)

With both options, if there are changes you did using the web interface of GitHub that conflict with changes you did locally, your will have conflicts that you have to resolve manually.

If everything goes well (no conflicts), the two operations (merge or rebase) will result in the same content, but different ordering of commits. With merge, if you look at the history using `gitk`, you will see two branches that merged into one. With rebase, you will see a straight line, with the changes on the web interface appearing first, and your local changes appearing later. This also means that the commit ids of the rebased revisions will have been rewritten. Some people find the straight line of history looks more organized. But in any case, as I said earlier, the content of your files will be exactly the same.

I know you asked for merging changes to one specific files. But the two Git branches (GitHub and your local) have diverged, and only the merge or rebase operations can bring them back together. There are other, less cleaner ways to get what you want, but it's best if you use either of these recommended ways.

Answer (score -1):

With git, Pull is actually a fetch and merge, so as long as you have committed your local changes, they will still be on your local repository, you'll ljust have another commit added, which is the README.md edition.  You're missing a big point of VCS which is branching, which would've been a good idea for you local repository.

Comment: I don't think that manually applying the changes made through the web interface is a good advice.

Comment: @danijar I agree, however as a last resort it is an option, it just doesn't take advantage of a VCS or git.

Comment: Given the situation, I think now is the best time for the thread starter to learn about merge conflicts. So it's good that you removed that paragraph.